# Randomly rearrange array items c#

Tags: c#, arrays, random, int

I have a c# int array that contains numbers from 1 to 100
that means that

```
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
....
myArray[99] = 100;
```

But I want to rearrange them in this array randomly, is it possible in c# ?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Random and Linq, you can do it easily:

```
Random r = new Random();

myArray = myArray.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
```

The above provides a random sort order for each element in the array using a `Random` object.

You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file in order to use `OrderBy` extension method.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How would that generate duplicates ? If the original array has unique numbers.

Comment: _"provides a random sort order"_ - well, random, but not as random as can be.

Comment: @فراساليحياوي it is one element inside the array. OrderBy is a loop internally. x is one element in the array in one iteration. as if you said `foreach(var x in myArray)`